# Is there a way to save a gganimate object as a HTML page with animation control buttons?

Tags: r, animation, gganimate

## Goal

To control the animation using start/stop/pause buttons.

## Problem

The `animation` package can save the created animation as a HTML page using the `saveHTML()` function ([example here](https://yihui.org/animation/example/savehtml/)). But it requires "`expr` = an R expression to be evaluated to create a sequence of images" as the first argument.

However, `gganimate` creates a `gganim` object, and I can't seem to find a function that can save the animation as a HTML page with buttons. The available `anim_save()` function does not save as HTML. Is there a workaround to do that?

#### Example code for animation

If you have any ideas please share. For your reference, I'm putting below the `gganimate` code from its website.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  # Here comes the gganimate code
  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me in RStudio, though I didn't see "current" listed as an option for device in `gganimate::animate`:

```
library(gganimate)
library(animation)

# name the above gganimate example as p
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')

# pass the animate command to saveHTML
saveHTML(animate(p, 
                 nframes = 10,         # fewer frames for simplification
                 device = "current"), 
         img.name = "gganimate_plot", 
         htmlfile = "gg.html")
```

I got a html file with animation control buttons & an image folder with 10 png files.